# how to rename fasta file headers using sed

Tags: sed, fasta

i know this is pretty easy but i can't get it to work. I am trying to rename the header using sed and evnethough the reg experssion works but i can't rename the fasta header. Here is  an small example. I have a multi sequence fasta file something like below

```
>Bra000001
CTTATTTTCTCCTTCACCACCGTACCACAGAAAAAAACTGTGATTTTAAA
AGCCACATTTACTTCTTTTTTTGTTGGGTCTAAATGTTAAAATAACATGT
>Bra000002
TTTATGTAGTACTGGACTAATCGGGTAGGGAAACAATCTTGATTTAGCAA
TACAGTGTAATAACTAATAATCATATTCATATTCCATAAATCCAAATGTT
```

Now i just want to add "Brassica rapa" at the end of fasta header like this

```
>Bra000001 Brassica rapa
CTTATTTTCTCCTTCACCACCGTACCACAGAAAAAAACTGTGATTTTAAA
AGCCACATTTACTTCTTTTTTTGTTGGGTCTAAATGTTAAAATAACATGT
>Bra000002 Brassica rapa
TTTATGTAGTACTGGACTAATCGGGTAGGGAAACAATCTTGATTTAGCAA
TACAGTGTAATAACTAATAATCATATTCATATTCCATAAATCCAAATGTT
```

I am doing this for making it work

```
grep ">" in.fa | sed 's/$/ Brassica rapa/' > out.fa
```

However by doing this i can only change the headers but no sequence info here. Ideally i want to both change the header and keep the sequence as it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use only [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) with its substitute command, checking if the line begins with `>` character, group the whole line and append your string at the end, like:

```
sed 's/^\(>.*\)$/\1 Brassica rapa/' infile
```

It yields:

```
>Bra000001 Brassica rapa
CTTATTTTCTCCTTCACCACCGTACCACAGAAAAAAACTGTGATTTTAAA
AGCCACATTTACTTCTTTTTTTGTTGGGTCTAAATGTTAAAATAACATGT
>Bra000002 Brassica rapa
TTTATGTAGTACTGGACTAATCGGGTAGGGAAACAATCTTGATTTAGCAA
TACAGTGTAATAACTAATAATCATATTCATATTCCATAAATCCAAATGTT
```

Comment: This might be a little simpler: `sed '/^>/ s/$/ Brassica rapa/'` -- for lines beginning with a `>`, change the end of the line to the given string. Or, like yours without the capturing parentheses: `sed 's/^>.*/& Brassica rapa'` -- where `&` gets replaced with the matched text.

Comment: Thanks all of them worked. I have a question though. Is 'sed' grouping works the same as 'R' grouping?

Comment: @glennjackman: Good alternatives. Probably both of them faster than mine.

Comment: @upendra: I don't know about `R`. I can't help with that. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

`awk` does this nice and simple.

```
awk '/^>/ {$0=$0 " Brassica rapa"}1' in.fa >out.fa
>Bra000001 Brassica rapa
CTTATTTTCTCCTTCACCACCGTACCACAGAAAAAAACTGTGATTTTAAA
AGCCACATTTACTTCTTTTTTTGTTGGGTCTAAATGTTAAAATAACATGT
>Bra000002 Brassica rapa
TTTATGTAGTACTGGACTAATCGGGTAGGGAAACAATCTTGATTTAGCAA
TACAGTGTAATAACTAATAATCATATTCATATTCCATAAATCCAAATGTT
```

Comment: Jotne, can you tell me what number '1' is there for? I tried removing it and it didn't work and when i changed it to other numbers such as '2' and '3' (just to making sure it is there for grouping similar to awk above) it worked irrespectively.

Comment: @upendra This is the most used command in `awk`.  When you have a number from `1`and up, it will be a true test, and do the default action `print`, so  `1` = `1 {print}` = `1 {print $0}`

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/^>/ s/$/ Brassica rapa/' YourFile
```

or

```
sed 's/^>.*/& Brassica rapa/' YourFile
```

Comment: sorry for duplicate reply, did not yet read comment from glenn jackman on reply of Birei when post mine